# Ubuntu 2021.04 How to delete nautilus smb credentials

Tags: nautilus, smb

There is a 6 year old answer which does not work. I selected 'remember forever', but entered the wrong details, and cannot find out how to tell nautilus to forget smb credentials. How do I do this?

Comment: Would a reinstall be a viable option for you? If so,  `sudo apt install nautilus-admin --reinstall`

Comment: If this option doesn't reset the config files, there is always the `remove --purge` route, but I've heard some purge-related horror stories recently. It's always worked perfect for me, but I've seen posts on here where trying to purge the config of some random app ends up [deleting the APT package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648160/how-do-i-remove-older-versions-of-gpg-on-raspbian-os/648162?noredirect=1#comment1218061_648162) itself...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04 (but I think this has been the same for some time now):

- open "Passwords and Keys"
- find the entry you want to change
- right-click - "delete"

Reconnect the smb share in Nautilus and enter the correct username/password